# Selecting button in a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

how could i select the button with class "btn btn-default" and also the link inside "btn-group group dropdown" and adding a fade effect using jQuery?

```
<body class="wg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1 class="banner-font">Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group button-banner">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="getSummary(1)"
                >Home</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="getSummary(5)">Contact Us</button>                   
                <div class="btn-group group dropdown">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tentang Kami <span class="caret"></span></button>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="getSummary(2)">Sejarah</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="getSummary(3)">Visi Misi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="getSummary(4)">Program Studi</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="isi">
                    <!-- ini isi nya -->
            </div>
            <footer>
                <b>
                    &copy; 2013 Kurnia Fredy Wijaya & Luki Ramadon <br>
                    Fakultas Teknik Universitas Pancasila
                </b>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're asking?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.btn-default').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.btn-group').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what u want mate.. :)

```
$('.btn-group.dropdown').on('click',function(){
    if($('.dropdown li').is(':visible')){
    $('.dropdown li').fadeOut(1000);   
    }else{
    $('.dropdown li').fadeIn(1000);
    }
 })
```

Check out the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CsXfP/

Note:

In case you use an older version of jQuery,replace `on` with `delegate`(preferred) or `live`

Comment: [`live()`](http://api.jQuery.com/live/) was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed entirely in 1.9; I suspect that the OP does not want that method, unless you know he's using an older version of jQuery somehow?

Comment: Thanks, but in older versions [`delegate()`](http://api.jQuery.com/delegate/) was recommended over `live()`.

Comment: tanx again @DavidThomas ;)